# Unable to compile awesome-icons.less

Tags: css, less, font-awesome

I have a main.less file that I'm trying to compile with font-awesome (6.3.0) classes.
I have this message error :

```
unable to compile less to css. Continuing...
org.lesscss.LessException: ParseError: Unrecognised input in D:/java/git/OpenScanDispatch/web/war/OpenScanDispatch/awesome-icons.less on line 8, column 5:
       each(.fa-icons(), {
         .@{fa-css-prefix}-@{key}::before { content: @value; !important;}
***** All completed @ Wed Mar 15 17:00:25 CET 2023  ***
```

Do you have a solution ?